# SQLite in Android How to update a specific row

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse, sqlite

I've been trying to update a specific row for a while now, and it seems that there are two ways to do this. From what I've read and tried, you can just use the:

`execSQL(String sql)` method

or the:

`update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` method.

(Let me know if this is incorrect as I am new to android and very new to SQL.)

So let me get to my actual code.

```
myDB.update(TableName, "(Field1, Field2, Field3)" + " VALUES ('Bob', 19, 'Male')", "where _id = 1", null);
```

I am trying to accomplish this:

Update Field1, Field2, and Field3 where the primary key (_id) is equal to 1.

Eclipse gives me a red line right underneath the word "update" and gives me this explanation:

> The method update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]) in the type
>   SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String,
>   String, null)

I'm guessing I'm not assigning the ContentValues correctly. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

First make a ContentValues object :

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Field1","Bob"); //These Fields should be your String values of actual column names
cv.put("Field2","19");
cv.put("Field2","Male");
```

Then use the update method, it should work now:

```
myDB.update(TableName, cv, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
```

Comment: Eclipse is giving me red underlines on "Field1", "Field2", and "Field3". Suggestions?

Comment: sorry, I thought they are variables declared in your code. Put them in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for being the first one with the correct answer. Saved me a lot of time. Much appreciated.

Comment: what if i want to check, if that row exists in table or not and then decide whether to update or insert a row?

Comment: It's actually a walk-around. The Third param of db.update() should be the where clause only, and the fourth is the actual condition values. In this case, the line should be: `myDB.update(TableName, cv, "_id=?", new String[]{id})`. SQLite will automatically fill the fourth param into the "?" in the third param, i.e. the WHERE clause. If your third param contains n "?"s , the fourth param should be a String[] of length n

Comment: @Akhil Your method would not work in some circumstances, for example, if the value contains symbols.

Comment: I'm having error with this, because the id column was declared as integer. How to fix this since new String[]{id} only accepts string?

Comment: @lance2k I guess you found Integer.toString() in the meantime...

Comment: @CristianoYL What do you mean with "symbols"? put() works with strings. SQLite works with strings. Please show an example what you thought that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 55):

Simple way:

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE myTable SET Column1 = someValue WHERE columnId = "+ someValue;

myDataBase.execSQL(strSQL);
```

Comment: This code will throw IllegalArgumentException. If you execute query without ContentValues it'd be much better to avoid using second argument at all. Like: myDataBase.execSQL(strSQL);

Comment: using `execSQL()` for updates won't work. Read [execSQL() with UPDATE doesn't update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17026633/2408342).

Comment: There is a serious security risk in doing this because someone can pass an SQL statement to 'someValue' variable, which could alter the whole database. Therefore always try to do prepared statements when doing any database operations.

Answer (score 44):

At first create a *ContentValues* object :

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Field1","Bob");
cv.put("Field2","19");
```

Then use the update method. Note, the third argument is the where clause. The "?" is a placeholder. It will be replaced with the fourth argument (id)

```
myDB.update(MY_TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
```

This is the cleanest solution to update a specific row.

Comment: The best way since using ? is safe.

Comment: And what does that ? do?

Comment: The parameter approach with ? is the best and most safe way. This should be the accepted answer. Never use string concatenation when composing sql statements!

Comment: how to use when where clause contains two fields?

Answer (score 27):

1. I personally prefere .update for its convenience. But execsql will work same.
2. You are right with your guess that the problem is your content values. You should create a ContentValue Object and put the values for your database row there.

This code should fix your example:

```
 ContentValues data=new ContentValues();
 data.put("Field1","bob");
 data.put("Field2",19);
 data.put("Field3","male");
 DB.update(Tablename, data, "_id=" + id, null);
```

Answer (score 15):

you can try this...

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE DB_TABLE SET YOUR_COLUMN='newValue' WHERE id=6 ");
```

Answer (score 7):

You try this one update method in SQLite

```
int id;
ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
con.put(TITLE, title);
con.put(AREA, area);
con.put(DESCR, desc);
con.put(TAG, tag);
myDataBase.update(TABLE, con, KEY_ID + "=" + id,null);
```

Answer (score 7):

hope this'll help you:

```
public boolean updatedetails(long rowId, String address)
  {
     SQLiteDatabase mDb= this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
   args.put(KEY_ROWID, rowId);          
   args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
  return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null)>0;   
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

use this code in your DB
      `

```
public boolean updatedetails(long rowId,String name, String address)
      {
       ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
       args.put(KEY_ROWID, rowId);          
       args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
       args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
       int i =  mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null);
    return i > 0;
     }
```

for updating in your sample.java use this code

```
  //DB.open();

        try{
              //capture the data from UI
              String name = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString().trim();
              String address =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString().trim();

              //open Db
              pdb.open();

              //Save into DBS
              pdb.updatedetails(RowId, name, address);
              Toast.makeText(this, "Modified Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              pdb.close();
              startActivity(new Intent(this, sample.class));
              finish();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG_AVV, "errorrrrr !!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    pdb.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Can try like this:

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("name","aaa");
values.put("publisher","ppp");
values.put("price","111");

int id=sqdb.update("table_name",values,"bookid='5' and booktype='comic'",null);
```

Answer (score 2):

if your sqlite row has a unique id or other equivatent, you can use where clause, like this

```
update .... where id = {here is your unique row id}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error as stated in my question. I did change the third parameter (String whereClause) to `"where _id = 1"`.

The change is also reflected in my question as well.

Answer (score 2):

For updates, need to call setTransactionSuccessfull for changes to get committed like so:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    db.update(...) 
    db.setTransactionSuccessfull(); // changes get rolled back if this not called
} finally {
   db.endTransaction(); // commit or rollback
}
```

Answer (score 2):

//Here is some simple sample code for update

//First declare this

```
private DatabaseAppHelper dbhelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```

//initialize the following

```
dbhelper=new DatabaseAppHelper(this);
        db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

//updation code

```
 ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
                values.put(DatabaseAppHelper.KEY_PEDNAME, ped_name);
                values.put(DatabaseAppHelper.KEY_PEDPHONE, ped_phone);
                values.put(DatabaseAppHelper.KEY_PEDLOCATION, ped_location);
                values.put(DatabaseAppHelper.KEY_PEDEMAIL, ped_emailid);
                db.update(DatabaseAppHelper.TABLE_NAME, values,  DatabaseAppHelper.KEY_ID + "=" + ?, null);
```

//put ur id instead of the 'question mark' is a function in my shared preference.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void updateRecord(ContactModel contact) {
    database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, contact.getFirstName());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LAST_NAME, contact.getLastName());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_NUMBER,contact.getNumber());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_BALANCE,contact.getBalance());
    database.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact.getID()});
    database.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this way

```
  String strFilter = "_id=" + Id;
  ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
  args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
  myDB.update("titles", args, strFilter, null);**
```

Answer (score 1):

Method for updation in SQLite:

```
public void updateMethod(String name, String updatename){
    String query="update students set email = ? where name = ?";
    String[] selections={updatename, name};
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, selections);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will demonstrate with a complete example

Create your database this way

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

    class DBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
            val createProductsTable = ("CREATE TABLE " + Business.TABLE + "("
                    + Business.idKey + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                    + Business.KEY_a + " TEXT, "
                    + Business.KEY_b + " TEXT, "
                    + Business.KEY_c + " TEXT, "
                    + Business.KEY_d + " TEXT, "
                    + Business.KEY_e + " TEXT )")
            db.execSQL(createProductsTable)
        }
        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            // Drop older table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Business.TABLE)
            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db)

        }
        companion object {
            //version number to upgrade database version
            //each time if you Add, Edit table, you need to change the
            //version number.
            private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1

            // Database Name
            private val DATABASE_NAME = "business.db"
        }
    }
```

Then create a class to facilitate CRUD -> Create|Read|Update|Delete

```
class Business {
    var a: String? = null
    var b: String? = null
    var c: String? = null
    var d: String? = null
    var e: String? = null

    companion object {
        // Labels table name
        const val TABLE = "Business"
        // Labels Table Columns names
        const val rowIdKey = "_id"
        const val idKey = "id"
        const val KEY_a = "a"
        const val KEY_b = "b"
        const val KEY_c = "c"
        const val KEY_d = "d"
        const val KEY_e = "e"
    }
}
```

Now comes the magic

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context

    class SQLiteDatabaseCrud(context: Context) {
        private val dbHelper: DBHelper = DBHelper(context)

        fun updateCart(id: Int, mBusiness: Business) {
            val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
            val valueToChange = mBusiness.e
            val values = ContentValues().apply {
                put(Business.KEY_e, valueToChange)
            }
            db.update(Business.TABLE, values, "id=$id", null)
            db.close() // Closing database connection
        }
    }
```

you must create your ProductsAdapter which must return a CursorAdapter

So in an activity just call the function like this

```
internal var cursor: Cursor? = null
internal lateinit var mProductsAdapter: ProductsAdapter

 mSQLiteDatabaseCrud = SQLiteDatabaseCrud(this)
    try {
        val mBusiness = Business()
        mProductsAdapter = ProductsAdapter(this, c = todoCursor, flags = 0)
        lstProducts.adapter = mProductsAdapter


        lstProducts.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, arg3 ->
                val cur = mProductsAdapter.getItem(position) as Cursor
                cur.moveToPosition(position)
                val id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Business.idKey))

                mBusiness.e = "this will replace the 0 in a specific position"
                mSQLiteDatabaseCrud?.updateCart(id ,mBusiness)

            }

        cursor = dataBaseMCRUD!!.productsList
        mProductsAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("ExceptionAdapter :",""+e)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(key1,value1);    
cv.put(key2,value2); /*All values are your updated values, here you are 
                       putting these values in a ContentValues object */
..................
..................

int val=myDB.update(TableName, cv, key_name +"=?", new String[]{value});

if(val>0)
 //Successfully Updated
else
 //Updation failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have completed this kind of code for update the row of a database, this is the code of Database handler class

```
public Boolean updateData(String id,String name,String age,String gender){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ID,id);
    contentValues.put(NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(AGE,age);
    contentValues.put(GENDER,gender);

    sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,ID+"= ?",new String[]{id});
    return true;           //Boolean value return korbe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public long fillDataTempo(String table){
    String[] table = new String[1];
    tabela[0] = table; 
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(DBOpenHelper.DATA_HORA, new Date().toString());
    args.put(DBOpenHelper.NOME_TABELA, nome_tabela);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, STRING + " LIKE ?" ,tabela);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**just give rowId and type of data that is going to be update in ContentValues.**

public void updateStatus(String id , int status){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

data.put("status", status);

db.update(TableName, data, "columnName"  + " = "+id , null);

}