# How to update Sqlite database for only one column using WHERE clause in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQLite in Android How to update a specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798473/sqlite-in-android-how-to-update-a-specific-row)

Is it possible to update database for one column using where statment
And this was my table structure and i need to update "messagestatus" column using "id".

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS autosms(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,phonenumber VARCHAR(15) ,message VARCHAR(5000) , year VARCHAR(10) , month VARCHAR(10) , date VARCHAR(10) , hour VARCHAR(10) , minute VARCHAR(10) , messagestatus VARCHAR(10))");
```

I tried with this, but with out Success theres an  warning "No such column Send"

```
public void update(int id)
{
        String s = "Send";
        db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("data/data/com.example.schduled_messages/SMS_Schdule_Sample.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        db.execSQL("UPDATE autosms SET messagestatus="+s+" WHERE id="+id+""); 
    }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Can't get you. Can you explain it more?

Comment: I need to update messagestatus using id, but i cant... how to do that?

Comment: This was my problem, i cant able to update.. thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to update only one Column?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9798579/265167

Answer (score 19, accepted):

String values must be enclosed in quotes:

```
"UPDATE autosms SET messagestatus='"+s+"' WHERE id="+id+""
```

I've added a quote here `'"+s+"'`

Without it, here is how your string expands:

```
"UPDATE autosms SET messagestatus=Send WHERE id=1234
```

SQLite will try to find a column called Send and set messagestatus to its' value.

Comment: thanks Simon. Let me check with this...

Answer (score 0):

From the doc on the [execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method:

Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

You should use the [update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method instead