# execSQL() with UPDATE doesn't update

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I am trying to use `rawQuery` and `execSQL` methods for manipulating my database, instead of the `.update`, `.insert`, etc. I am trying to perform an UPDATE with the following code:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE configuration " +
                "SET number_fields = " + number_fields + ", "
                + "frequency = " + frequency + ", "
                + "ag = " + ag + ", "
                + "number_alarms = " + number_alarms + ", "
                + "failed_rapper = " + failed_rapper + ", "
                + "max_mv = " + max_mv + ", "
                + "max_nav = " + max_nav + " "
                + "WHERE serial_id = " + Integer.toString(id) + ";");
```

AFter this action there is a log that states an update has occurred and it seems to work, yet when I try to do a select statement on the table, it returns with the following error:

```
06-10 10:01:47.564: W/System.err(3815): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Now I have performed that same SELECT on different data in Android that I manually inserted using SQLite Database Browser and it works fine. I have also performed that same UPADTE in the SQLite Browser and it has worked there. Therefore I know that the problem is that the UPDATE command is not working when running on Android.

**Question:** Why does the UPDATE command not work within the `execSQL()` method?

Comment: At first glance your UPDATE statement looks correct.  Have you double checked that all column names are spelled correctly (this often gets me)?  Additionally, are you sure that all of your variables are initialized and contain valid values for the columns where they'll be inserted into table? (Stepping through with the debugger can help verify this).  If both of those things are correct, perhaps you could post your SELECT code, since that's where the actual error occurs.

Comment: @MattDavis it appears that the table is not initialized with proper values and then when updating the new values don't commit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see! Glad that you figured it out.  Does the execSQL method end up working for an update when the table is initialized properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Android SQLiteDatabase class documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.
>
> It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected
>   rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String,
>   ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et
>   al, when possible.

Then later:

> For UPDATE statements, use any of the following instead.
>
> update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])
>
> updateWithOnConflict(String, ContentValues, String, String[], int)

As far as I can tell, the `execSQL` method is more for higher level database operations, such as creating tables and changing schema, and the `.query`, `.update`, `.delete`, etc. methods should be used to modify rows.  I'm not sure you have another option besides [`.update`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to perform this operation.

Answer (score 2):

here is an sample update Query:

```
public boolean updateCartTable(String retailerName, String mCouponId){
        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(TableConstantName.COUPON_ONLY_STATUS, 1);
        values.put(TableConstantName.COUPON_SRORE_DEALS_STATUS, 1);
        values.put(TableConstantName.COUPON_CATAGORY, "C");
        try {
            sDb.beginTransaction();
            final boolean state = sDb.update(TableConstantName.COUPON_TABLE, values, TableConstantName.CART_COUPON_RETAILER_NAME + "=" + "'"+retailerName+"'"+ " AND "+TableConstantName.CART_COUPON_ID + "=" + "'"+mCouponId+"'", null)>0;
            sDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
            return state;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            sDb.endTransaction();
        }
    }
```