# SQLite does not update

Tags: java, android, sqlite, updating

im trying to update the value of the column "done" for an entry.
COLUMN_DONE saves an Integer.

```
public void markAsDone(int date_id, int t_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_DATES_T + " SET " + COLUMN_DONE + "= 1 WHERE date_id IS '" + date_id + "' AND t_id IS '" + t_id + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }
```

But it doesnt update the value of this entry. What did I wrong???

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execSQL() with UPDATE doesn't update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026633/execsql-with-update-doesnt-update)

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget ; in the end of your query?
Try

```
String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_DATES_T + " SET " + COLUMN_DONE + 
               "= 1 WHERE date_id IS '" + date_id + "' AND t_id IS '" + t_id + ";'";
```

Comment: Horrendous idea. The **;** is completely **useless**.

Comment: In SQL it mandatory thing as long as i remember, but i could be wrong

Comment: You are really wrong. In **other** databases, which support multiple SQL commands on the same line, **;** is used to separate those commands.

Comment: The SQL standard *requires* a  semicolon at the end of each statement. Most databases (including SQLite) make it optional if there is only a single statement. But in any case, putting the semicolon *inside* the `t_id` string is wrong.

Comment: @CL for Access and SQL Server it's competely optional, for a single statement. Anyway, great catch for spotting out that the semicolon was inside the string delimiters!