# How to update a SQLite database in android?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to update an SQLite database table with an integer value.I have tried 2 approaches the first one does not update the table and the 2nd one gives an SQLiteException. 
1st using the update method:-

```
public void updateBookQty(String quantity,String bookId)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int updateQty = getQuantity(bookId) - Integer.parseInt(quantity) ;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QTY,updateQty);


    try{

        db.update(BOOKS_TABLE, values, KEY_BOOK_ID+ " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(bookId) });

        Log.d("BookUpdate", String.valueOf(updateQty));

    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Log.d("UpdateError",e.toString());
    }

}
```

2nd using execSQL:-

```
public void updateQty(Integer qty,String bookId)
{
    int originalQty = getQuantity(bookId);
    int updateQty = originalQty - qty;
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String rawQuery = "update "+BOOKS_TABLE+" set "+KEY_QTY+" = "+updateQty+ " where "+KEY_BOOK_ID+" = "+bookId+" ;" ;
        db.execSQL(rawQuery);
        db.close();
        Log.v("UpdateQty", "Qty updated");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here I get a SQLiteException:-

> System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0000169":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: update books_table set
>   quantity = -10 where book_id = BK 0000169 ;

Comment: Dont use `execSQL` for updating, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027063/3635454

Comment: `db.update` returns an `int` which is the the number of rows affected. Are you sure it returns `0` in your case? Moreover since `bookId` is a String there is no reason doing: `String.valueOf(bookId)`, just pass the `bookId` variable

Comment: @pleft I tried removing String.valueOf for bookId. and yes I tried logging the number of rows affected it returns 0. What do you think might be causing this problem.

Comment: Can you update your question and post some info about the database table `books_table` along with the row you want to update? I suppose that it probably there is no match in your `where` clause, means that no `book_id` value is the same as the value of parameter `bookId` (BK 0000169). But you have to give us more info so please update the question

Comment: @pleft I was passing the wrong id to be updated.There was no problem with the code.

Comment: Great, so please accept the answers below which addressed the exception problem

Comment: @pleft thanks a lot.Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
public void updateQty(Integer qty,String bookId)
 {
   int originalQty = getQuantity(bookId);
   int updateQty = originalQty - qty;
try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String rawQuery = "update " + BOOKS_TABLE + " set " + KEY_QTY + " = " + updateQty + " where " + KEY_BOOK_ID + " = '" + bookId + "';";

    db.execSQL(rawQuery);
    db.close();
    Log.v("UpdateQty", "Qty updated");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: thank you, this solved the SQLiteException.I was actually passing the wrong id that was the reason why the DB wasn't updating.

Answer (score 1):

As your id is string you must quote the value, esp. It contains space:

```
String rawQuery = "update "+BOOKS_TABLE
    + " set "+KEY_QTY+" = "+updateQty
    + " where "+KEY_BOOK_ID+" = '"+bookId+"';" ;
```

Comment: Now I don't get an error but it does not update the database.