# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: l

Tags: android, sqlite

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: kia (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE people_chat SET msg = kia WHERE name = uol

final String CREATE_QUERY4 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+PEOPLE_CHAT+ "("+ "id INTEGER primary key autoincrement,"+ "name TEXT NOT NULL ,"+ "msg TEXT NOT NULL "+ ")";
```

List item

```
 public void upDateMsg(String name,String msg){
        Log.i(TAG, "UpdateData: "+msg);
        String strSQL = "UPDATE people_chat SET msg = "+msg+" WHERE name = "+ name;
        db.execSQL(strSQL);
        Log.i(TAG, "Update Success: "+strSQL);
    }
}
```

Comment: add code snippet as well log cat

Comment: why you are not using ContentValues?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798473/sqlite-in-android-how-to-update-a-specific-row

Comment: Change query to `String strSQL = "UPDATE people_chat SET msg = '"+msg+"' WHERE name = '"+ name+"'";`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
UPDATE people_chat SET msg = 'kia' WHERE name = 'uol'
```

You are missing single quotes. Change code to:

```
 String strSQL = "UPDATE people_chat SET msg = '"+msg+"' WHERE name = '"+ name+"'";
```

**Note:** As pointed out in comments, If name contains single quotes, then the query would fail. It must be escaped accordingly.

Comment: This will blow up when a string contains a quote.