# Android SQLiteDatabase WHERE statement breaks UPDATE

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to update an **SQLiteDatabase** but for some reason **update** always fails and returns 0 (rows updated).

If I remove **String selection = null;**, then all rows are updated, but I just want to update the row *WHERE eId = ?* and I provide the eId. All of the values in ContentValues are correct and non null. Been racking my brain for hours now..maybe a fresh set of eyes on this will help, thanks in advance!

NOTE: **propertyItem** is OK and all of the values coming from my form are correct. The problem breaks at update when I use the selection variable.

```
/// COLUMN_NAME_EID == "eId"
public int updatePropertyItem (PropertyItem propertyItem) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if ( propertyItem.title != null )values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, propertyItem.title);
    if ( propertyItem.category != null ) values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY, propertyItem.category);
    if ( propertyItem.serial != null ) values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SERIAL, propertyItem.serial);
    if ( propertyItem.note != null ) values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE, propertyItem.note);
    if ( propertyItem.purchaseDate != null ) values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PURCHASE_DATE, propertyItem.purchaseDate);
    if ( propertyItem.currentValue != null ) values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CURRENT_VALUE, propertyItem.currentValue);
    if ( propertyItem.replacementValue != null ) values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_REPLACE_VALUE, propertyItem.replacementValue);
    if ( propertyItem.store != null ) values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STORE, propertyItem.store);
    values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_WARRANTY, propertyItem.warranty);
    values.put(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FAVORITE, propertyItem.favorite);

    String selection = DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EID + " = ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(propertyItem.eId) };

    int rowsUpdated = db.update(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);

    db.close();
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using update as `int rowsUpdated = db.update(DatabaseContract.DataEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EID + " = " + propertyItem.eId, null)` ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a register stored in database with provided eId?

Comment: may i know that the data type of DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EID column?

Comment: you are passing String for this Column value, so you have to put you string with single quote like: 'propertyItem.eId'.

Comment: I have a list of property items in a ListView, so I know that these items exist in a database. propertyItem.eId is not null and I have tried with single quote. COLUMN_NAME_EID is a String

Answer (score 0):

You could try what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798473/sqlite-in-android-how-to-update-a-specific-row)

By setting 
`selection = DatabaseContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EID + "=" + propertyItem.eId;` and passing `null` as the final argument for `update`

And then if in the future you need to extend the `where` clause just use `StringBuilder`

Comment: I have tried by passing selectionArgs as null, no  luck there either.