# Android Sqlite update first row only

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

I need to update only the first row of a specific sql query command

my code is:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String strSQL = "UPDATE table SET column = something WHERE  name = john AND age = 10";
    db.execSQL(strSQL);
```

I have like 5 results with the same criteria of name=john and age of 10

this works to update the last item however I want it to update the first row result only of the WHERE clause. how can this be possible?

Comment: better use a unique column to identify your users, and 
for updating the first item `cursor.moveToFirst();` should work

Comment: I already have unique id for each user, but I'm just providing an example in my question. Isn't there a method to update the row from a single line instead of creating a cursor and updating the first one?

Comment: then use limit like the answer says

Comment: not working ...

Comment: do not write a raw query, find the item using limit and then use `yourdb.update(tablename,contentvalues,where,whereargs[])` to update
like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798527/8528047

Comment: Find the id of the *first* record (What determines order?) and update just that one.... `UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn = whatever WHERE id = the_id_you_care_about`.

Comment: try "UPDATE table SET column = something WHERE  name = john AND age = 10 ORDER BY unique_column DESC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE table SET column = something WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = john AND age = 10 LIMIT 1)";
```

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIMIT": syntax error (code 1):

Comment: Using `LIMIT` with `UPDATE` in sqlite requires creating a custom version of the sqlite3.c amalgamation (Passing `--enable-update-limit` to the configure script in the sqlite3-src-XXXXXX.zip distribution), and compiling that with a specific option turned on (`SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`), btw. Probably not an option given android.

Comment: @MoDev I've modified my answer

Comment: do not write a raw query, find the item using limit and then use `yourdb.update(tablename,contentvalues,where,whereargs[])` to update
like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798527/8528047

Comment: @MoDev Did you check?

Comment: I believe it works! however I had another issue which prevented the change to be applied. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Provided id is a PK, try

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = something 
WHERE id = (SELECT min(t2.id) 
            FROM table t2 
            WHERE t2.name = 'john' AND t2.age = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** 
(in your case) If you want to update only first row then add one more parameter in your table. It will help you to find that record uniquely

**Second:**
Don't use update query like this

```
    String strSQL = "UPDATE table SET column = something WHERE  name = john AND age = 10";
```

do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798527/5705721) instead